# Extract XML from Axis TypeDesc

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, apache-axis

Using Eclipse I have created a web service client from a WSDL file. Everything is good in that I can instantiate my service call Java object and set the required fields.

My problem is that I can't figure out a way to extract the request XML before making the service call. I need to see the request XML being generated against the web service.  Any help appreciated.

This is my service call object that was auto generated by Eclipse:

```
public class ClientPrice implements java.io.Serializable {
     private java.lang.String clientKey;

 // Type metadata
    private static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc typeDesc =
        new org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc(MedicareReprice.class, true);

    static {
        typeDesc.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://services.com", "MedicareReprice"));
        org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
        elemField.setFieldName("clientKey");
        elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://services.com", "ClientKey"));
        elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
        elemField.setNillable(false);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
        typeDesc.addFieldDesc(elemField);
    }

    /**
     * Return type metadata object
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.description.TypeDesc getTypeDesc() {
        return typeDesc;
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Serializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Serializer getSerializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanSerializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }

    /**
     * Get Custom Deserializer
     */
    public static org.apache.axis.encoding.Deserializer getDeserializer(
           java.lang.String mechType, 
           java.lang.Class _javaType,  
           javax.xml.namespace.QName _xmlType) {
        return 
          new  org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BeanDeserializer(
            _javaType, _xmlType, typeDesc);
    }
}
```

This is how I make the actual call against web service, but I need to extract request XML before invoking web service.
I tried using the TypeDesc object but not returning XML.

```
ClientPrice  price = new ClientPrice();
price.setClientKey("12345");

ProcessingLocator serviceLocator = new ProcessingLocator();
IProcessing service =  serviceLocator.getSecureSoap11();
//Help here. How can I extract XML before invoking web serice????
Results results = service.invokeWebService(price);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never, I had the exactly same problem, here is how I figure out.

```
public static String serializeAxisObject(final Object obj, final boolean removeNamespaces, final boolean prettyPrint)
{
    final StringWriter outStr = new StringWriter();
    final TypeDesc typeDesc = getAxisTypeDesc(obj);
    QName qname = typeDesc.getXmlType();
    String lname = qname.getLocalPart();
    lname = lname.substring(1);

    qname = removeNamespaces ? new QName(lname) : new QName(qname.getNamespaceURI(), lname);
    final AxisServer server = new AxisServer();
    final BeanSerializer ser = new BeanSerializer(obj.getClass(), qname, typeDesc);
    final SerializationContext ctx = new SerializationContext(outStr, new MessageContext(server));
    ctx.setSendDecl(false);
    ctx.setDoMultiRefs(false);
    ctx.setPretty(prettyPrint);
    try
    {
        ser.serialize(qname, new AttributesImpl(), obj, ctx);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
       //throw new Exception(“Unable to serialize object ” + obj.getClass().getName(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String xml = outStr.toString();

    if (removeNamespaces)
    {
        // remove any namespace attributes
        xml = xml.replaceAll(" xmlns[:=].*?\".*?\"", "")
        .replaceAll(" xsi:type=\".*?\"", "");
    }

    return(xml);
}

public static TypeDesc getAxisTypeDesc(final Object obj)
{
    try
    {
        final Class objClass = obj.getClass();
        final Method methodGetTypeDesc = objClass.getMethod("getTypeDesc", new Class[] {});
        final TypeDesc typeDesc = (TypeDesc) methodGetTypeDesc.invoke(obj, new Object[] {});
        return(typeDesc);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

how to use it

```
serializeAxisObject(new ClientPrice(), false, false);
```

I hope that helps

Comment: There is already a method generated by WSDL2java; getSerializer shown above.
Why do you need to new BeanSerializer(xx...) ?